# Draw string on the center of the header image

Tags: java-me, midp, lcdui

I am creating a login screen and I want to add an header to the form and write text on the center of the header image.

I am able to draw the header using ImageItem in j2me. But I am stuck up with writing the text on the header.

Comment: what code did you try so far?

Comment: I used ImageItem add the header. But is there any other way to write the text on image other than canvas. I am new to J2ME.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its better to use canvas for your purpose. In canvas you can add image and also you can draw string anywhere on canvas. Use canvas to done string on the center of the header image.
[check this url for example of image](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/J2ME/Drawimmutableimageonacanvas.htm) so you can understand how to use it.

Comment: Thanks Sajid! Any other way it could be done other than the canvas?

Comment: Canvas is better solution for that... No other solution for that. Check other Canvas examples to understand, its very easy.

Comment: Yeah.. I got it. I used customItem class and appended it to the form.Thanks!!